# How to make a Lightstick (Firework)

Tags: animation, materials

This is a simple question, How do I make something like this in Blender?

I already did the flying sparks but I cant seem to recreate this part right here... It seems to be a very intense fiery glow but I dont know how to do it.

[LIGHTSTICK](http://img10.deviantart.net/12e6/i/2012/022/f/b/loosis_or_lusis_by_emilialight-d4n8jk5.jpg)

Comment: That is a Sparkler and the streaks trail the particles by way of long shutter exposure. The photo is exposed for a long period allowing the spark to streak across frame. It is a  challenge to recreate in Blender as motion blur may not work for particles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the particle render type "lines" and increase the amount of trailing particles to emulate a streak.

[image: lines particles]

To get the sparkles you may have to duplicate the particle system and use different render settings. make sure to keep the dynamics the same or they will diverge.